# Native Modules in React Native: requiresMainQueueSetup

Tags: ios, react-native

I have created a Native Module for iOS to handle some low-level TCP and UDP socket networking, and have noticed that my app sometimes crashes when requiresMainQueueSetup is set to NO. I always assumed main queue setup was not required for this kind of low level stuff, but never really looked into it until now. The RN documentation does not mention anything about this method, and even on their Github issue list there isn't any useful information.

So my question simply is: what are the rules to determine if a native module needs requiresMainQueueSetup to be true or false?